# Add If else condition to click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like do something like that with Jquery, make condition to click function :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  if {

    $("li#menu-item-1101").click(function(){     
    $( '#menu-item-1101' ).addClass( 'current_page_item' );

  }else{ // I clik on another <li> than #menu-item-1101 I remove current_page_item class     
    $( '#menu-item-1101' ).removeClass( 'current_page_item' );    
  }

  });

});
```

Anyone can help me please?
Thank you!!

Comment: not that much clear. please elaborate with simple example.

Comment: Do you want to add and remove class on same button click???

Comment: I thing you are trying to achive this with navigation menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want logic something similar to this:

On click of `li` you want to check the `id` of it and add/remove class accordingly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("li").click(function(){ 
        if($(this).attr("id") == "menu-item-1101")
        {
            $(this).addClass( 'current_page_item' );
        }
        else
        {
            $( '#menu-item-1101' ).removeClass( 'current_page_item' );
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Work like a charm! Thank you very much vijawP!

Answer (score 0):

it is possible by adding an id to each `<li>` element and write a generic jquery function with if else.

html:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li id='itm1'>item 1</li>
  <li id='itm2'>item 2</li>
  <li id='itm3'>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

script:

```
$('.nav li').click(function(){

var id=$(this).attr('id');

if(id=='itm1'){//first li clicked}
else if(id=='itm2'){//second li clicked}
else{//third li clicked}

})
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are doing the code it seem that you have to set lots of li conditions. But you can do it like:

HTML Part :

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li id='menu-item-1101'>item 1</li>
  <li id='menu-item-1102'>item 2</li>
  <li id='menu-item-1102'>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery Part :

```
$(function(){
    $(".nav li").click(function(){
        if($(".nav li").hasClass("current_page_item")){
            $(".nav li").removeClass("current_page_item");
        }
        $(this).addClass("current_page_item");
    })
})
```